# Could the Shop owner cancel recurring application charge without uninstalling the app?

Tags: shopify

I'm as Shop owner installed the App and subscribed to the application recurring charge.

Could I someway cancel the recurring charge without uninstalling the App? for example from my shop admin dashboard?

I know that I can cancel recurring charge:

- From the App
- By uninstalling the App

But my question is concrete about some button/option in the dashboard, do I have some possibility cancel recurring charge without uninstalling the App?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you asking if a merchant that installed the App and accepted a charge can also cancel that charge from their shop?

Comment: @DavidLazar yes

Comment: Adding a link to a resource would be one way, or just add that cancel subscription button to the homepage of the App.

Comment: @DavidLazar  yes, you right, from the app the shop owner (merchant) could cancel recurring charge by the "cancel subscription" button or just by uninstalling the App. But does it possible to-do(cancel recurring charge) without interacting with App? For example from the store admin panel (some-store-origin.myshopify.com/admin). Thank you.

Comment: As I said, YES, but only by interacting with the App via a link or button in the App. You cannot avoid interacting with the App so your question really makes no sense except in the context of a button in the admin as if it belonging in the admin, which, at this time, you cannot really do.

Comment: @DavidLazar my question was exactly about the possibility to cancel subscription without interaction with App.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

## Cancel recurring application charge

Your app should be able to cancel any recurring_application_charge it has created a charge with -

> DELETE /admin/api/2020-07/recurring_application_charges/{recurring_application_charge_id}.json API call

You can have the functionality inside your service. Please note that the to resubscribe the merchant to a charge the merchant would need to accept the charge. You won't be able to activate the cancelled charge.

Link to documentation - [https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/billing/recurringapplicationcharge?api[version]=2020-07#destroy-2020-07](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/billing/recurringapplicationcharge?api%5Bversion%5D=2020-07#destroy-2020-07)